# How do I reinforce a cardboard antenna for outside use?

Tags: antenna, isolation, tv

I bought Mohu Releaf cardboard antenna. It works much better outside than inside. Mohu explicitly advises against outdoor use of its indoor models, yet I wrapped it in a plastic bag and hung it out of window.  It looks a bit shabby so I am looking for ways to improve both the look and protection against elements.

I tried placing antenna between window glasses yet it gets less channels than outside. I have a big outside antenna, again it gets less channels.

[image]

Dimensions: 9″ x 11.5″

Effect of elements on Leaf antennas
http://mohu.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/4000026474-can-i-use-my-leaf-curve-antenna-outside-or-in-an-attic-

Releaf model
https://releaf.gomohu.com/#specs

I am considering to check the car paint I have for conductivity in microwave and paint the antenna.
Other ideas are self-adhesive laminate poach, epoxy resin or a plastic container

Comment: How does your big external antenna not pick up the same channels? Did you reorientate it?

Comment: cardboard one is more modern, advance that is why it is better in channel picking. Extrernal one is just simple 4 bay bowtie. It is sturdy yet not as capable in picking the channels

Comment: I moved around both antennas and even the cable for some time. the same spot works best for both. My appartment is at the first floor and I do not consider moving

Comment: From what I can find the leaf is also a bowtie antenna.

Comment: Interesting. Do you know what is inside releaf? In either case I guess not all bowties are the same

Comment: https://www.disablemycable.com/blog/mohu-leaf-teardown/ the re leaf is just the non powered 50 design in recyclable material.

Comment: so if I find/buy an external amplifier, I would probably get more channels or even can move it inside without loosing a channel

Comment: Maybe. https://www.disablemycable.com/mohu-leaf/ For a not very scientifically accurate comparison. An amplifier may affect the signal if it's already good. And distance from antenna to TV is also a factor. RF is basically witchcraft. It wouldn't hurt to try.

Comment: Not sure omni directionality just explains everything. For one, I hang the antennas right in front of metallic mosquito net. Yet clearly there are situation when DB4 beats the leaf.

Comment: adding old Terk amp does not seem help much